# Pre-launch report exception: IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called

Tags: android, google-play-games

Following the update of multiple games with Google's Play Games Services sign-in integration the following exception appeared in the pre-launch reports:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=969353318, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signinflow.SignInActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:5347)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult (ActivityThread.java:5386)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute (ActivityResultItem.java:67)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute (ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2308)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7898)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
  at m.ggn.e (ggn.java)
  at m.hpz.aQ (hpz.java:7)
  at m.hpz.T (hpz.java:3)
  at m.bw.a (bw.java:7)
  at m.sm.e (sm.java:6)
  at m.cjf.onActivityResult (cjf.java)
  at m.cjo.onActivityResult (cjo.java)
  at hck.public_onActivityResult (hck.java)
  at xub.onActivityResult (xub.java:4)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult (Activity.java:8613)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:5340)
```

The issue appeared on multiple games, only in pre-launch report, with the following setups:

1. Pixel 7, Android 13, RU
2. Pixel 6, Android 12, EN & FR
3. Pixel 5, Android 11, EN
4. Samsung SM-G981U1, Android 10, EN & AR

After resuming deployment the issue did not reproduce in production. Is this a pre-launch device issue?

**Update (23.03.2023)**: The issue did not reproduce in production. It's probably a pre-launch reporting issue.